# Learning Javascript but stuck on a simple return keyword

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript so please be kind. I have the following code and unable to understand what is wrong but I need not so much a direct answer but an understanding of what th issue is:

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = function(timesTwo){
    print(newNumber);
};

timesTwo(4);
```

I am following the tutorials on Code academy for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = function(number){
    console.log(timesTwo(number));
};

newNumber(4);
```

try this one ..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it by thinking about it: I realised my syntax was incorrect.

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = timesTwo(2);
    console.log(newNumber);
```

The above works.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here comes break down of your code

```
// here you define a function named 'timesTwo' which receive a number as parameter, so 'TimesTwo' is a function, in Javascript, function is also a type , can be assigned to variable, so here you assign function to variable 'timesTwo'
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

// Here you defined another function called newNumber and passed a function as parameter, first of all, the parameter timesTwo is never used in this fuction,
// secondly, you are trying to print a variable newNumber which is not defined in the scope of this function, remember, javascript has function scope
var newNumber = function(timesTwo){
    print(newNumber);
};

// you finally called 'timesTwo' function with parameter 4 , which return value 8, but this is no statement to print it out, that's why you don't get it print on screen
timesTwo(4)
```

To make it work as you intended, use @Alok 's code above

### References:

[Javascript scope and context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

[Javascript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)